# Flutter GestureDetector strangely not working after the recent update

Tags: flutter, dart

so I created this widget but the gesture detector could not work at all.
the print method didn't print anything
I don't know if this was a Flutter bug after the recent update or it's because my phone is Android 11 and it's also updated recently.
there is no error message, no exceptions, it works fine on the other file.

here's the problematic code:

```dart
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              showMoreChronology = !showMoreChronology;
              setState(() {});
              print('hmm');
            },
            child: MyCard(
              color: theme.colorScheme.background,
              padding: R.spaces.betterSpaceAround,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(width: double.infinity),
                  Text(
                    localizations.chronology,
                    style: R.styles.normalFont.copyWith(
                      color: theme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae facilisis sapien. Fusce et varius ipsum. Sed elementum leo nibh. In risus ante, semper non lacinia et, molestie et justo. Fusce sit amet dignissim dui. Duis feugiat enim dui, ut ''',
                    style: R.styles.normalFont.copyWith(
                      color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    ),
                    maxLines: showMoreChronology ? null : 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  R.spaces.betterSpaceWidget,
                  Text(
                    localizations.more,
                    style: R.styles.normalFont
                        .copyWith(color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

and here is my `MyCard` class file:

```dart
    Card(
      margin: margin ?? R.spaces.noSpaceAround,
      elevation: elevation,
      color: color ?? theme.colorScheme.surface,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: borderRadius ?? CustomBorderRadius.all(),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: (padding ?? R.spaces.littleSpaceAround) +
            verticalPadding +
            horizontalPadding,
        child: child,
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution is very simple. just stop debugging and re-compile the app.
it appears that the application didn't install properly or something is wrong on the mobile side. That's why the hot reload didn't work as expected and as a result, the UI won't be updated after hot reload or hot restart.

you can see the indicator at debugging console if there's no spammy message (when you debugging on android) like this:

```
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](28996): processMotionEvent MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=119.0, y[0]=1638.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8426205, downTime=8426205, deviceId=4, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](28996): dispatchPointerEvent handled=true, event=MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=119.0, y[0]=1638.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8426205, downTime=8426205, deviceId=4, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](28996): processMotionEvent MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=119.0, y[0]=1638.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8426328, downTime=8426205, deviceId=4, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](28996): dispatchPointerEvent handled=true, event=MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=119.0, y[0]=1638.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8426328, downTime=8426205, deviceId=4, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
I/flutter (28996): hmm
```

Then this could be you don't install the application properly.
just try to unplug and replug and re-compile the app or maybe for the last effort try to uninstall first. If none works seek help.